# Can't deploy Rails app to Heroku, "Invalid RUBY_VERSION"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to push my app to Heroku, but I can't get past this error:

```
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1554/1554), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1652/1652), 23.93 MiB | 369 KiB/s, done.
Total 1652 (delta 859), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
 !
 !     Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified: There-was-an-error-in-your-Gemfile,-and-Bundler-    cannot-continue.
 !     Valid versions: ruby-2.0.0, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.8.7, ruby-1.9.3-jruby-    1.7.0, ruby-1.8.7-jruby-1.7.0, ruby-1.9.3-jruby-1.7.1, ruby-1.8.7-jruby-1.7.1, ruby-1.9.3-rbx-2.0.0dev, ruby-1.8.7-rbx-2.0.0dev
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p448. I followed the steps [here](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku), and the top of my Gemfile includes:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

When I run "heroku run 'ruby -v'" it returns ruby 1.9.2p290. What's going on?

Edit: Here's my whole Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'i18n'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'rest-client'
require 'addressable/uri'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

Comment: You’ll need to post your entire `Gemfile`. Heroku is trying to determine the Ruby version you’ve specified by calling `bundle platform --ruby`, but you have an error somewhere in it and Bundler is returning `There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.`. Heroku isn’t detecting this as an error, and is treating the message as the Ruby version, which obviously doesn’t exist and so results in the error you see (this is arguably a bug in the Heroku buildpack). To fix it you’ll need to track down the error in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post with my whole Gemfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your `Gemfile`, in the line `require 'addressable/uri'`. You can’t use `require` inside a `Gemfile`. The load path hasn’t been set up yet, so you get a `LoadError` which Bundler catches and produces an error message.

Heroku is trying to use `bundle platform --ruby` to determine the version of Ruby you want to use, but is not properly detecting the error condition and treating the error message as the version. This is obviously not a valid version, and so it produces the error you are seeing.

I’m guessing you’re using `require` because to use the Addressable gem you need to require either `addressable/uri` or `addressable/template` (or both) and you can’t just use `require 'addressable'`. In this case you can use the `:require` option of Bundler:

```
gem 'addressable', :require => 'addressable/uri'
```

If you do need to require more than one thing, you can use an array:

```
gem 'addressable', :require => ['addressable/uri', 'addressable/template']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if this changes your situation, as your Gemfile almost looks like mine, but for these changes.

1)Of course, assuming you are in your Rails Root folder and your `less Gemfile` is the actual one above. You did also `bundle` too after changes.

2) change 
`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

3) *optional* Heck, try switching version to `ruby '2.0.0'` just to get passed it.

4) I think this is needed too:

`gem 'rails_12factor'`

All these tricks should make it work at least.

EDIT

Why is `require 'addressable/uri'` there? remove this and add `gem 'addressable'` instead.

Comment: The `rails_12factor` gem is not a requirement for uploading to Heroku, only a recommendation. Even for a Rails 4 app.

Comment: Either way, the heroku apps i've been uploading haven't worked too well without it. Rec or not.